# How can I tell if Hazelcast's IMap.putIfAbsent() worked?

Tags: hazelcast

I need to put a key into a Hazelcast map, and throw an error if the key already exists in the map. This must be done in an atomic way, so testing if the key is there first and then doing the put in a separate operation won't work.

Here's the problem: the only way to tell if putIfAbsent() actually put anything is to test if the returned object is the new one or the existing one. But Hazelcast doesn't return the existing one; it returns a clone of it. So you can't do `if (old == new)` to test. You would have to do `if (old.equals(new))`. The trouble is that my objects are large and complicated and it's not going to be easy to implement a custom .equals() methods.

Surely there's a better way to do this. Does Hazelcast has a different way to do an atomic putIfAbsent()?

Edit:

I've run into a similar problem with IMap.replace(). In order to supply the old and the new values, I have to clone the old value, modify it, call replace(), and be sure that I have an equals() method on my value that will do the comparison. There has got to be a better way. It would be good if Hazelcast would somehow give me a version number or a timestamp for an object in a map so I could do a compare-and-set on the version number or the the timestamp, instead of having to deal with every field of a complicated object.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try an EntryProcessor.

map.executeOnKey(key, PutIfAbsentEntryProcessor(value))

This PutIfAbsentEntryProcessor you need to implement yourself and it returns true of the original value (you have access to that in the EntryProcessor) is null or not.